# Why am I not getting output for the following code?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I am not getting output for the following code in jupyter notebook.
This code basically checks for even length of words and prints them out. 
I find out that after appending each word in "new"(list) the while loop doesn't even work.

I know there are other methods to do this in much simpler way but I want this to work.

```
st = 'Print every word in this sentence that has an even number of letters'
new=[]
i=0
for words in st.split():
    new.append(words)
l=len(st)
while i<=l:
    if len(new[i])%2==0:
        print(new[i])
        i=i+1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues. For example, `l = len(st)` should be `l = len(new)`, `i <= l` should be `i < l` and `i=i+1` needs to be dedented.

On another note, a much better way to do this would be

```
st = "Print every word in this sentence that has an even number of letters"
for word in st.split():
    if len(word) % 2 == 0:
        print(word)
```

Comment: can u explain me why (i<=l) should be (i<l) (should we not check the last word) and why (i) should not be incremented?

Comment: @AshishRaju of course. there are 13 words in your sentence, and since `i` is starting from 0, you only need to go up to 12, as 0 to 12 is actually 13 items if you count the 0.

Comment: @AshishRaju so the `i=i+1` line is in the right location, but you just need to remove one tab (or four spaces) from in front of it so it is inline with the if statement

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how to fix your code, because it has too much errors. Just written the **closest** possible solution

```
st = 'Print every word in this sentence that has an even number of letters'
words = st.split()

for w in words:
    if len(w)%2==0:
        print(w)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `i=i+1` happens inside the `if` statement. That means that i never progresses past 0, since the first word has an odd length. To fix this, put the i=i+1 outside of the `if` statement.

```
while i<=l:
    if len(new[i])%2==0:
        print(new[i])
    i=i+1
```

Answer (score 0):

You receive an infinite cycle because the first condition is not satisfied and increase in i does not happen.

Answer (score 0):

## Issues with your code:

```
st = 'Print every word in this sentence that has an even number of letters'
new=[] # You can create the list of words here instead of a loop
i=0
for words in st.split():
    new.append(words)
l=len(st)    # len(new)
while i<=l:  # i < l (since indexing of i starts from 0 to n-1 length
    if len(new[i])%2==0:
        print(new[i])
        i=i+1 # this needs to be outside loop, since it will only increment if even word is found
```

## Updated code:

```
st = 'Print every word in this sentence that has an even number of letters'
new = s st.split()
i = 0
l = len(new)
while i < l:
    if len(new[i])%2 == 0:
        print (new[i])
    #else:
    #    pass
    i = i+1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
st = "Print every word in this sentence that has an even number of letters"
new=[]
i=0
for words in st.split():
    new.append(words)
l=len(words)
while i<l:
    if len(new[i])%2==0:
        print(new[i])
    i=i+1
```

Additionally, you can perform the same task using:

```
st="Print every word in this sentence that has an even number of letters"
[word for word in st.split() if len(word)%2==0]
```